# Flutter nested scrolling not working properly on Android

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter SingleChildScrollView containing a column containing multiple vertical listviews.  On an Android device, when a listview reaches its max extent in either direction, continued scrolling on the listview should cause the outer SingleChildScrollView to scroll  - but it does not.  It does work on a PC in a browser though.  Any suggestions for how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

1. ```
    ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    )
   ```
2. Use `CustomScrollView` instead.

Comment: I already tried CustomScrollView, it didn't solve the problem.  "NeverScrollable" stops the Listview from scrolling at all, which is not what I want.

Comment: I can't understand your mean，provide a design reference if you can。

Comment: The achieve that you you want to is like the "CoordinatorLayout" which in android app?

Comment: Jeremy Caney solution does not work.  Why in the world has it got two upvotes.